# Imagem com CSS - manipulação imagem e título

Tags: css, imagem

Quero colocar uma imagem atrás do título no topo da página, colocando o título para direita e centralizado e um parágrafo a esquerda contendo alguns dizeres, porém estou com um problema:
Não consigo colocar a imagem atrás do título sem usar a propriedade `position: absolute;` o que faz com que não dê para colocar o título a direita.

Segue o código HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="arquivo.css" type="text/css" />
        <title>titulo</title>
    </head>
    <header>
        <h1>título</h1>
        <p>blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá blá</p>
        <p>blá blá blá bláblá blá blá bláblá blá blá blá </p>
    </header>
    <div id="imagemtopo"  style="width:30%">
        <img src="img/imagemtopo.png" alt="Logotipo">
    </div>
    <body> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Segue código CSS:

```
.h1 {
    position: right;

}

#imagemtopo{
    width: 120em;
    height: 20em;
    min-height: auto;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Como uma imagem fala mais do que mil palavras, segue uma para melhor entendimento do meu problema:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu não entendi bem o que você quer. Mas será que colocar a imagem como background não te ajuda a deixá-la atrás do titulo sem precisar usar position: absolute?

Comment: Seria melhor até meter duas imagens, uma de como tem agora e outra de como queria que ficasse. Isso ajuda a clarificar para que vai responder à pergunta e faz com que não tenha respostas que não cumpram o que espera

Comment: @LuísHenriqueFaria Coloquei uma imagem pra ficar mais clara a pergunta.

Comment: Legal! Tentou fazer como eu falei? Vai funcionar.

Comment: Concordo com o @LuísHenriqueFaria . `background-image` no `<header>` resolve o problema com elegância. Podendo ainda controlar quanto da imagem aparece, etc..

Comment: `position: right;` não existe.